# Exact sequences of pairs

Tags: homological-algebra

Take a triple of topological spaces $(X, A, B)$ consists of a topological space $X$ and two subspaces $A,B$ with $B \subseteq A \subseteq X$. 
Why is the following sequence of pairs exact? 
$$ 0 \rightarrow (A,B) \xrightarrow{i} (X, B) \xrightarrow{j} (X, A) \rightarrow 0$$
where $i, j = \text{inclusion}$.

Comment: What is your definition of an exact sequence of pairs of spaces?

Comment: @EricWofsey I don't believe an exact sequence of pairs would differ from a regular exact sequence; that is, we need that im(i) = ker(j).